# Finding Table Start Location Index using Google Docs API

Tags: javascript, google-docs-api

I want to make a InsertTableRow Request via Docs API and it requires a TableStartLocation.
I used

```
var tableName = table[0];
foreach (var element in document.Body.Content)
if (element.Table != null)
{
   var checkTable = element.Table.TableRows[0].TableCells[0].Content[0].Paragraph.Elements[0]
                            .TextRun.Content.TrimEnd('\n'); //Get Text Value in first cell of the table
                        
   if (tableName.Equals(checkTable)) // Check if the table is the table that I want to add rows
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Add Table Row");
          TableUpdateRequest(ref requests, table, element.StartIndex); // Using element(StructuralElement) to get StartIndex
          break;
      }
}
```

To find all table in a document and tried to use the `element.StartIndex` as Table Start Location but i got: `Google.GoogleApiException : Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Invalid requests[5].insertTableRow: Invalid table start location. Must specify the start index of the table. [400]`

What is a suitable index for Table Start Location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The `tableStartLocation` is necessary to identify the correct table

A way to retrieve it is e.g. with [documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get). To narrow down the results you can specify `fields`, e.g. `body/content(startIndex,table)`.

This will return you a resource of the type

```
{
  "body": {
    "content": [
      {},
      {
        "startIndex": 1
      },
      {
        "startIndex": 2,
        "table": {
          "rows": 4,
          "columns": 3,
          "tableRows": [
            {
             ...
```

In other words: You know now that your `tableStartLocation` is `2` - same as the table's startIndex.

Sample

```js
  var resource = { "requests": [
    {
      "insertTableRow": {
        "tableCellLocation": {
          "tableStartLocation": {
            "index": 2
          }
        },
        "insertBelow": false
      }
    }
  ]
                 }
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, documentId);
```

Now, depending on your document, you might have several tables and might want to compare names etc. before deciding which is the start index of the correct able.

Comment: Finally got my problems solved. Turns out that I have to get updated element in every loop as the start index might change when batchUpdate is performed. :)